# Proxying/relaying a mysql connection (so that the server appears to be on localhost)

Tags: mysql, database, networking, tunnel

I have a MySQL server running on host A in my LAN.
Host B has an application running that expects a MySQL server listening on default port, locally.

I need *something* that will listen on host B and relay everything to the real MySQL server.

What am I looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you're looking for something like [mysqlproxy](http://forge.mysql.com/wiki/MySQL_Proxy)!

Comment: That had to be one of the slower days. Thanks!